# Spring Security OAuth2 login redirect to error page despite being successful

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

As to not reveal confidential information, the provider will be replaced by `$PROVIDER`.

The authorization works, but instead of redirecting me to the index, it redirects me to `/error`.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Start the application
2. Go on any page, it will redirect me to `http://localhost/oauth_login` which displays a link `login`.
3. Click on the link `login` (which links to `http://localhost/oauth2/authorization/$PROVIDER`)
4. Get redirected to `http://localhost/error`

The error page displays the following (I formatted it for readability):

```
{
    "timestamp":"2018-04-05T14:18:47.720+0000", 
    "status":999, 
    "error":"None", 
    "message":"No message available"
}
```

This is obviously the same parameters shown on the default *Whitelabel Error Page*, so really, the only problem is that it's in JSON except of being an HTML page. If I refresh `http://localhost/error` after, it shows me the normal *Whitelabel Error Page*.

Now this is where it gets weird, if I try to navigate to `http://localhost/` after having been redirected to the error page, I am authenticated (the user data is there, so the authorization was successful). Basically, the issue is that I am redirected to `http://localhost/error` instead of `http://localhost/`.

Because it is fully functional (aside from the redirection), I will not post the whole security configuration, but I will instead limit it to relevant code:

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/oauth_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/oauth_login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/oauth_login").permitAll()
    ;
}
```

**Relevant properties**

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.$PROVIDER.redirectUriTemplate=http://localhost/login/oauth2/code/$PROVIDER
```

**Relevant information**

- Once I am authenticated on the website, I can navigate, refresh the page, do whatever I wish (until I log out).

**TL;DR** Authorization works but redirected to `/error` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually found the answer to my own question, but I decided to post it anyways in case somebody runs into the same issue.

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
```

should have been

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
```

If you don't set it to `true`, it will automatically redirect the user to the last previous request, and in my case, the last request is made to the url `/error`, which explains my problem.

By setting it to `true`, you force the user to be redirected to whatever your `defaultSuccessUrl` is.

By looking at the logs, you can actually see it:

```
2018-04-05 11:04:09 DEBUG [-nio-80-exec-10] RequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler : Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: http://localhost/error
2018-04-05 11:04:09 DEBUG [-nio-80-exec-10] o.s.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy : Redirecting to 'http://localhost/error'
```