# An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: spring, spring-oauth2, oauth2client

I am trying use spirng-oauth2-client to connect my project with a third-party authentication server (following this [instruction](https://developers.mercadolivre.com.br/en_us/authentication-and-authorization#Server-side)), ans right now when I run the application, after the authorization step, I am redirect back for my application, and a page with this error is displayed:

```
[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 406 Not Acceptable: [Media is not supported]
```

In the [comments for an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61022167/2692962) in another Stack Overflow post, someone suggested that this is happening because "Spring makes the POST for the authenntication code with FORM parameters, whereas mercadolibre expects no body, only query parameters".

I have this configuration right now:

**application.properties**

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.provider=mercadolivre
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.client-id=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.client-secret=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mercadolivre.authorization-uri=https://auth.mercadolivre.com.br/authorization
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mercadolivre.token-uri=https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token
```

**security.java**

```
@Configuration
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .oauth2Login()
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to change the Spring behavior to match th required for the service? I mean, making the POST for the authenntication code with no  body, only query parameters?

Comment: Did you try to see what is the acceptable content type is in your redirected endpoint? Maybe you must specify the 
Accept: application/json or whathever the request send as data type.

Comment: where I specify that?

Comment: Your page seems to be the default oauth output from spring itself it means there is no configurations has been done to show the another page after successful authentication. Have you checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49675748/415749

Comment: I've tried this, but still got the same problem.

Comment: Can you please post response header of the 3,4,5 requests shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lIyy.png the service you are using mercadolivre thats too special to try from our side.

Comment: 3: https://imgur.com/a/HJRC6By, 4: https://imgur.com/a/csyMfYW, 5: https://imgur.com/a/ESImaBI

Answer (score 3):

For me the error was *[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized*

The issue was an expired/outdated Client Id and Secret. (I used the Client Id and Secret before and it worked)

Comment: This is a different error than in the question, so I believe you are not answering the given question, which answers are for.

Comment: This was the first link when i searched for my error, so maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This error relates to the response you get from the authentication server, either during client authentication or during fetching of the `user-info`. We can force the method for both requests to be `BASIC` instead of `POST` with these properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.client-authentication-method=BASIC
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mercadolivre.user-info-authentication-method=BASIC
```

Comment: Still not working for me. Posted question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67571950/an-error-occurred-while-attempting-to-retrieve-the-oauth-2-0-access-token-respon

Answer (score -1):

In you controller tha you is redirected for, try to put consumes Json like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String indexPage() {
    .
    .
}
```

Or `MediaType.ALL_VALUE`

Comment: This response is not coming from the server, it's coming from the authentication provider `mercadolivre.com`, this is why this configuration is irrelevant.